# GnuCash and ledger/hledger

Tags: gnucash

I am using GnuCash 2.6.7 under Mac OS X 10.10.4 to do my personal finance. I have a fairly large account structure by now with many expense accounts to track different categories of spending.

I would like to use [ledger](http://www.ledger-cli.org/), or preferably [hledger](http://hledger.org/), to work on that data which I have created with GnuCash.

Is there a way to import my accounts, transactions etc into (h)ledger? What is the most painless/recommended way to do it?

Comment: This is a software question, not a personal finance question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we answer questions about money, we don't offer tech-support for money software

Comment: Derek, Nathan, according to this logic all GnuCash questions should be closed!

Comment: @gojira GnuCash questions that relate to **financial** features and issues may be on topic, but this question is about data import/export, not financial features, and is best asked at http://superuser.com. See also this relevant post at our meta site: http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/9/do-technical-questions-about-tools-belong

Comment: @Chris W. Rea: I understand your point, though I disagree, but anyway, can we maybe migrate my question and answer somehow instead of just closing it? I think it is of interest to GnuCash/(h)ledger users who use this for their personal finance.

Comment: I agree the technical solution is worth preserving. I don't know if there is a migration path enabled between these two sites, but you can ask & answer your question at Super User. It is on-topic there and ought to survive, IMHO. I've posted there often myself. (There's also the Apple SE, but I see more GnuCash questions at SU.)

Answer (score 9):

Answering my own question, I figured it out: yes, there is a way, with a tool called `gnucash2ledger.py`.

- First, save the GnuCash book in sqlite3 format with "Save As..." (if
  you have an older version of GnuCash, make sure the appropriate
  database backend is installed).
- Use this command line tool to convert
  the sqlite3 books into ledger plain text format:
  https://github.com/MatzeB/pygnucash
- For example, if you saved the books in sqlite3 format from within GnuCash as `foobar.sqlite3`, you can convert it to ledger format like this: `python2 gnucash2ledger.py foobar.sqlite3 > foobar.txt`
- Note, this ASCII file will contain the account structure and the actual transactions. With the versions I could use for testing, this leads to errors. I removed the account structure leaving only the actual transaction entries (blocks starting with a date).
- For hledger, you [might](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.finance.ledger.hledger/1087) need to convert it additionally like this: `ledger -f foobar.txt print > foobar.journal`

Versions used: GnuCash 2.6.1, Ledger 2.6.2, hledger 0.22